# Backup gem in Rails 5 - Recommended practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, database-backups

I have a simple rails app running on a Digital Ocean droplet, I now want to add in functionality to take a backup of the (single) database on a regular basis.

I understand this is commonly completed using the `Backup` and `Whenever` gems in Rails e.g. http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/06/30/backup-a-rails-database-with-the-backup-and-whenever-gems/

The above tutorial takes you through the process of first installing the gem on the server and editing the files generated to suit your needs, it then briefly considers how you could replicate the changes locally on a development machine and push future changes to the live server.

The above process seems somewhat backwards, instead I would like to first create the files locally, before pushing these to the live server.

So far I have (locally):

- Installed a Rails 5 compatible version of `Backup` - `gem install backup -v5.0.0.beta.2`
- Generated the backup configuration files - `backup generate:model --trigger=db_backup --databases="postgresql" --storages="local" --compressor="gzip" --notifiers="mail"`
  This automatically creates a new folder (Backup) in the user's root directory, I have moved this new folder to the `Config` folder within my rails application
- Edited the contents of my credentials.yml.enc file to include details of the username, password, etc. for my Postgres database and email client - `EDITOR="sublime --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit` and referencing variables in the form `Rails.application.credentials.database_password`

I now hoped to reassure myself that this was working sensibly on my local environment before pushing the changes to my Git repository and to the live site. However, when I tried `backup perform -t db_backup` the following error arose `Config::Error: Could not find configuration file: '/Users/myname/Backup/config.rb'`

The documentation available on the `Backup` gem (http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/generator/) states:

> If you want to change the path where the model file will be
>   generated, use the --config-file option to specify the path to your
>   configuration file. Models will be placed into a models/ directory
>   where your configuration file is located.
>
> `$ backup generate:model --config-file='/path/to/my_config.rb'
>   --trigger my_backup (etc...)`

**Please could someone suggest what would be seen as good / best practice in terms of the location of this Backup folder, in particular ensuring this can easily be pushed to the server and that its location on the server can be easily referenced.**

Sorry if this is a daft question, but having tried "making things up as I go along" with previous tasks (and tying myself in knots), I'd be keen to learn from the experience of others in terms of how this is best done neatly

Answer (score 0):

After running `backup generate:model` you moved the backup config folder from your users directory `'/Users/myname/Backup/'` into the config directory of the rails app, `'/my_rails_app/config/Backup'`. So if thats correct, you should be able to perform the backups by specifying the new location of the config file with the `--config-file` option.

Instead of

```
backup perform -t db_backup
```

you should be doing

```
backup perform -t db_backup --config-file 'my_rails_app/config/Backup/config.rb'
```